# Twitter API Search - how to check query char length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I keep getting a Twitter 403 error for the search query being too many chars.

```
  search = Twitter::Search.new.contains("#{self.home_team.long_name} #{self.away_team.long_name} win OR lose")
  search.language("en").no_retweets.since_date(since)
```

How do I count how many chars the query is so I skip trying to run a search on it?  For ex, this one is 156 chars:

```
GET https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Middle%20Tennessee%20State%20Blue%20Raiders%20Florida%20International%20Golden%20Panthers%20win%20OR%20lose%20-rt%20-from%3Aespn&&lang=en&since=2011-02-09: 403: Sorry, your query is too complex. Please reduce complexity and try again.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the issue is your query length, it's the query complexity. Try reducing the complexity or amount of results you can get with a more restrictive query or a simpler one. This usually happens with geographically based queries, like near, where the radius is too large and results in a very computationally complex or large query.

If you still want to count the query length, you can probably get a good estimate of the length by counting up your parameters and keys, like this:

```
search = Twitter::Search.new.contains(....).language('en')
search.query.inject(0){ |sum, obj| sum += obj[0].size+obj[1].size+1 }
```

That should give you the length of the key+value+symbol of your query.